# How to merge two sql queries results? One query has GROUP BY

Tags: java, mysql, merge, group-by

**I have a table like below**

```
id, date, type, quantity, vendor
'1','2020-04-05','2424A','200','vendor1'

'2','2020-04-05','2424','350','vendor1'

'3','2020-04-05','2424A1','150','vendor1'

'4','2020-04-05','2425','400','vendor1'

'5','2020-04-05','MA5878','200','vendor2'
```

I am using Java as my backend. 
I have tried these queries

1. `SELECT vendor, type, quantity 
   FROM reports;`

```
vendor, type, quantity
'vendor1', '2511', '200'

'vendor1', '5120', '350'

'vendor1', '2520', '150'

'vendor1', '5114', '400'
```

2. `SELECT vendor, SUM(quantity) 
   FROM reports 
   where date = '2020-04-05' 
   GROUP BY vendor;`

```
vendor, SUM(quantity)
'vendor1', '1100'

'vendor2', '20600'
```

I need to combine the above 2 queries results. Can someone guide me to proceed further.

Comment: please show data as text not Images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT vendor, ont_type, quantity 
    FROM cpe_portal.ontfereports
), b as (
    SELECT vendor, SUM(quantity) as quantityb 
    FROM cpe_portal.ontfereports 
    WHERE date = '2020-04-05' 
    GROUP BY vendor
)
SELECT a.vendor, a.ont_type, a.quantity, b.quantityb
FROM a join b ON a.vendor = b.vendor
```